# How to say "unwanted" in terms of a person being unwanted

Tags: word-choice, phrases, phrase-requests

Trying to say something like this line:

> I am not wanted.

But for all the Japanese language likes skipping subjects and topics, I can't seem to find an equivalent for this case--it seems like the only way to say this is by rephrasing it to "X doesn't want me" (Ｘは私をいらない). The closest I can think of is 自分が必要とされていない, but I don't want to say "I'm not needed", I want to say "I'm not *wanted*". It doesn't seem like conjugating いる or ほしい is the way to go either. How can I say this without adding a topic?

<sub>※Disclaimer: This is not related to how I actually feel.</sub>

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify in what way you mean wanted - romantically, as part of a team, as company, for a specific request, etc. I would imagine the translation would be different depending on how you intend this word.

Comment: @Robert It would be 'in general' technically--not wanted by anyone or for anything, unwanted as a person. Essentially I want to leave it as open/all-encompassing as it is in English. If that isn't possible however, then it would be in the sense of a child being unwanted by their parents (or whatever else is closest to being all-encompassing).

Comment: @idlackage I'm a bit amused by the need to put the disclaimer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for

> 私は求められていない（よう）です。 (It seems) I am not wanted/needed.

The line between need and want case is a blur (I'd say the same in English), but the word does express a nuance of being unwanted.

Then again, I imagine the Japanese don't say this out loud often because it also expresses some resentment (of being unwanted by the listeners, perhaps).

Edit:
To say it more emphatically you could say,

> 私は誰にも求められていません。 Nobody wants/needs me.

Of course you can outright point out just who is making you feel unwelcome or unwanted, and that will border on being antagonistic.

Comment: Thank you. If google isn't lying to me, is this kind of a soft way to put it (even without the よう)? Would there also be a way to put this more bluntly/harshly? (Kind of like using いらない)

Comment: @idlackage Neither are softer or harsher than each other.

Comment: I would think that expressing ambivalence or ignorance for someone's presence is already harsh for Japanese... they are a community-based society, after all.

Comment: @keithmaxx Sorry for more questions but I just realized that I should've put in a lot more context than I did. What I was looking for was what someone would think in their head--they aren't saying this out loud, they're just alone sulking to themselves. Which is what I meant with いらない--like if someone asked whether you'd like a bag at the supermarket even いりません is kind of cold, so you'd say something like 大丈夫です. I would like to know if 求められていない would work as something someone (who is angry/sad about being unwanted) would think to themselves.